# Materialize UI dropdown closes when clicking its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

I have made a drop down search form based on Materialize for Wordpress:

```js
$('.dropdown-button').dropdown();
```

```css
.search-area {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  width: 400px !important;
  height: 100%;
  top: 4.2em !important;
}

.search {
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 0 50px 0 0 !important;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px -1px #e0e0e0 !important;
  cursor: default;
}

.search-header {
  float: left;
}

.search-ico {
  padding: 0px 10px 0 10px;
  background-color: #0063a3;
  margin: -13px 0px 0 0;
}

.input-field input[type="search"]+label {
  right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-activates="search-area" class="search-header dropdown-button"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a>
<div id="search-area" class="dropdown-content search-area">
  <form method="get" id="searchform" action="/">
    <div class="input-field">
      <input class="search" type="text" name="s" id="s" value="" placeholder="Search..." />
      <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="search-ico material-icons">search</i></label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

It works fine and displays the search area. My problem is when I click on the search input field to type something, the drop down just fades out and I cannot type anything.

I've also made a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/BanShee08/pen/vpoGZm) so you can see whats happens and where my problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually add an event listener to the `.dropdown-content` element and prevent clicks from bubbling using `e.preventDefault()`:

```js
$('.dropdown-button').dropdown();

// Add this:
$('.dropdown-content').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.search-area {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  width: 400px !important;
  height: 100%;
  top: 4.2em !important;
}

.search {
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 0 50px 0 0 !important;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px -1px #e0e0e0 !important;
  cursor: default;
}

.search-header {
  float: left;
}

.search-ico {
  padding: 0px 10px 0 10px;
  background-color: #0063a3;
  margin: -13px 0px 0 0;
}

.input-field input[type="search"]+label {
  right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-activates="search-area" class="search-header dropdown-button"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a>
<div id="search-area" class="dropdown-content search-area">
  <form method="get" id="searchform" action="/">
    <div class="input-field">
      <input class="search" type="text" name="s" id="s" value="" placeholder="Search..." />
      <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="search-ico material-icons">search</i></label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```